# Menu functionality for a basic paint app

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm on my way to design my own paint app in Java. I have designed the frame and the menu.

While I did read the related concepts, I need help in designing functionality. I just need help in defining the actionPerfomed method of the ActionListeners for new, open, save and exit.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class MyPaintBrush {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Paint Brush");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); // Dimension to make the frame fit the full screen
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
        JMenu menu_file = new JMenu("File");
        menu.add(menu_file);
        // Anonymous Objects:
        ActionListener listener_new = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

            }
        };
        ActionListener listener_open = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

            }
        };
        ActionListener listener_save = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

            }
        };
        ActionListener listener_exit = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

            }
        };
        JMenuItem item_new = new JMenuItem("New");
        item_new.addActionListener(listener_new);
        JMenuItem item_open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        item_open.addActionListener(listener_open);
        JMenuItem item_save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        item_save.addActionListener(listener_save);
        JMenuItem item_exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        item_exit.addActionListener(listener_exit);
        menu_file.add(item_new);
        menu_file.add(item_open);
        menu_file.add(item_save);
        menu_file.add(item_exit);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I just need help..."` is a bit over-broad for a stackoverflow question. ***Specifically*** what are you stuck on? Your code above shows only empty ActionListeners and does not show your best good faith attempt to solve this -- why not? Please don't cheat yourself by leaving this out or by not attempting this first. You've nothing to lose and all to gain.

Comment: I'm just a beginner and this is really daunting me. :(

Comment: I believe you, but again, you've nothing to lose by at least trying to solve it first. Else, how will we know where you're stuck? Else your question becomes essentially a "please someone code this for me" type question. Please don't let this happen.

Comment: I just figured out how to close. By inserting this in the body of the actionListener:  `System.exit(0);`

Comment: My main problem is this: save. I will add a Component and all the make some drawing, but how will I save them? I just heard of BufferImage.Is it the right thing to help me?\

Comment: YES!!! BufferedImage would be perfect. Look into using `ImageIO.read(...)` and `ImageIO.write(...)` to read and write BufferedImages.

Comment: [Pertinent links to similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+bufferedImage+body%3AImageIO)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BufferedImage` of the drawing and then write the `BufferedImage` to a `File`.

Check out [`Screen Image`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) for a class that both creates the BufferedImage and writes the BufferedImage to a file.

The basic code would be:

```
BufferedImage bi = ScreenImage.createImage(yourComponent);
ScreenImage.writeImage(bi, "component-Image.jpg");
```

The harder part is actually creating the drawing code:) Good luck.